# C# .NET development integration with C++ integration

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, architecture

Sorry for being lengthy.

I need an expert opinion on my problem of a design decision. We are going to implement a high end face recognition software. I am in search of matching technologies of achieving this.

As I think there are 2 general options.

1. Stand alone desktop application.
2. Web application.

We decided to go for a web application and which made us search possible ways of achieving this.

**Design decision construction**

ASP .net application where back end uses OpenCV wrapper [Emgu](http://www.emgu.com/) which implements face recognition and prepossessing activities.

As Emgu turned out to be that it lags with performance and parallelism. So, as many has said, going for a c++ development is good to keep the performance level as expected.

So, now we are in the process of finding a way to implement web application that uses OpenCV directly in the back end.

We have came across CPPCMS and TreeFrog frameworks which are c++ web frameworks.

We have another idea, Implement a c++ web service and then leave open front end for any development. This service also uses OpenCV directly.

1. Are we following the right direction?
2. Any suggestions on technology ingratiation and best approaches.
3. As we are .NET C# familiar, we are quite new to c++ development. If the
   implimentation can be carried out using visual studio

Comment: `we are quite new to c++ development`... it doesn't sound like a good idea to implement a `high end` product in technology that you don't know and which is far from trivial. Are you sure that your problems are really with Emgu implementation?

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic We would like to use Emgu wrapper and develop it as a c# application. But Emgu does not provide parallelism and high speed. Thanks

Comment: I understand that, but my point is that I would be very cautious about  learning c++ on a project requiring parallelism and similar stuff. It is easy to shoot yourself in the foot and spend eternity chasing subtle bugs.

Comment: Yes, Most probably, :(, What is your suggestion on this. That would be useful for us. Since we are going to use a framework, We are hoping to reduce those bugs. We are hoping to do brown field rather than green. That's why we are in hunt for better frameworks and the possibility of using visual studio in our project.

Comment: Hard to tell. Sounds like you have been using open source version of Emgu (which forces you to publish your code, BTW). Have you considered buying the commercial license which allegedly contains many performance optimizations (http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Licensing:#Commercial_License)

Comment: I have considered that initially. To be specific this is a final year project and they are expecting it to be opensource and expected to be implemented with no expense at all. There is no option rather than go with the hard way :(??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all CppCMS is frequently used for implementing web API like JSON-RPC or RESTful API.

So in general it is good idea.

Few notes about TreeFrog - it is relatively new project absolutely lacking documentation and IMHO it is quite raw...

*Disclosure: I'm the author of CppCMS*

Comment: Wow, I was unable to find documentation for implementing our project using cppCMS to get a start. If you can provide me with some resources, appreciate it.Other thing is, Can we use Visual Studio to use this framework. Thank you.

Comment: Start at cppcms.com, everything is there. And use VS is fully supported: <http://cppcms.com/wikipp/en/page/notes_for_windows_users>